# Facebook Plugin only visible when the user is logged on. How do I change this?

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

I hope someone can help me.  I have a Facebook Social Plugin on my website. However, people can only view it if they are logged into Facebook.  How do I make it visible even when people are not logged into facebook.  To view what I mean see [this](http://www.cbexpo.co.za)

Comment: Everette which social plugin you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Your page must have some restriction on it, I can see an error of 'This page can't be seen by the current user. Please check page privacy and visibility settings.' - If your page is limited to certain countries or age ranges the plugin won't be visible except to users who meet those restrictions